# Sonar server fails to start with unsatisfied dependency: class java.lang.String

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am trying to write a plugin for Sonar to define a new model. I started with the reference plugin which compiles with Maven and runs fine. When I add my class TestmodelDefinition.java, it still compiles fine, but when I restart the server I get a 503 error page and in the log there is a stack trace:

```
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: com.mycompany.sonar.reference.models.TestModelDefinition has unsatisfied dependency: class java.lang.String among unsatisfiable dependencies: [[class java.lang.String]] where org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@312cfd62:119<I<org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@12e90e23:7<I<org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@49b9a538:19<| was the leaf container being asked for dependencies.
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:188) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getGreediestSatisfiableConstructor(ConstructorInjector.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.access$100(ConstructorInjector.java:51) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:308) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:274) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:341) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:689) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:638) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:617) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:311) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:48) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:138) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:76) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:286) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:312) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:274) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:341) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:689) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:638) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:617) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:704) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:638) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:627) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:105) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:76) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:286) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:312) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:274) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:341) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.instantiateComponentAsIsStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1014) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addAdapterIfStartable(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1006) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:983) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:746) ~[picocontainer-2.10.2.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:70) ~[sonar-plugin-api-2.13.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:236) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:116) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformLifecycleListener.contextInitialized(PlatformLifecycleListener.java:33) [classes/:na]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224) [jetty-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50) [jetty-util-6.1.25.jar:6.1.25]
        at org.sonar.application.JettyEmbedder.start(JettyEmbedder.java:79) [sonar-application-2.13.1.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.application.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:50) [sonar-application-2.13.1.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [na:1.6.0_20]
```

I am using Eclipse on a Windows XP machine to write the code but it is compiled and run on a 64-bit Ubuntu 10.04 server edition.
I have tried simply adding

```
import java.lang.*;
```

but that didn't solve anything.

Edit:
Here is the TestmodelDefinition:

```
package com.mycompany.sonar.reference.models;

import java.lang.*;

import org.sonar.api.qualitymodel.*;
import org.sonar.api.measures.*;

public final class TestModelDefinition extends ModelDefinition {

  public TestModelDefinition(String name) {
    super(name);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

  @Override
  public Model createModel() {

    Model testModel = Model.createByName("ISO 9126 way");

    String parentName = "Maintainability";
    String name = "Testability";

    Characteristic parentCharacteristic = Characteristic.createByName(parentName);
    Characteristic newCharacteristic = Characteristic.createByName(name);

    CharacteristicProperty newProperty = CharacteristicProperty.create("Tests");

    parentCharacteristic.setEnabled(true);
    newCharacteristic.setEnabled(true);
    parentCharacteristic.addChild(newCharacteristic);

    testModel.addCharacteristic(parentCharacteristic);
    testModel.addCharacteristic(newCharacteristic);

    return testModel;
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us `TestModelDefinition`? Apparently it has a `String` dependency.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `java.lang.*` is imported automatically, there's no need to do it explicitly.

Comment: I figured as much when Maven reported successful build, but then the error confused me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String is not a type that can be injected by Pico container. You should provide a default constructor to your class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wiring problem.

> com.mycompany.sonar.reference.models.TestModelDefinition has
>   unsatisfied dependency:  class java.lang.String among unsatisfiable
>   dependencies: [[class java.lang.String]]

Make sure that the required 'String' object is injected.

Comment: I'm pretty new to java. how do I do that?